# Remove the padding of an inline span element

Tags: html, css, inline, padding

I have two inline elements. You may assume they are exactly the same, except the position of one is set to absolute and it's positioned below the other. Like this:

```
<body style="text-align: center;">
<span style="background-color: #000; color: white; font-size: 300px; line-height: 1; padding: 0; position: relative;">
    AAA <span style="background-color: #333; color: white; font-size: 300px; line-height: 1; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;">AAA</span>
</span>
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CSPFL/5/

And, of course, the full screen fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CSPFL/5/show/

The spans aren't the same height! The static span has padding of some kind. Is it possible to remove this padding, without changing the position to absolute? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: you can see they aren't the same height if you change left to 100% and top to 10%. They seem to be the same height in FF for Mac.

Comment: The fiddle URLs don’t work (404). They work if the “_bop/” part is omitted, but do they then refer to your newest versions?

Comment: I've changed Royi's example and I forgot to replace the hyperlink completely... Yes, it's the newest version.

Comment: This seems like a very strange way to align two elements.

Comment: Interesting. It also seems to be related to the font. E.G. If you use Verdana, the difference is larger than with Arial. And it has nothing to do with putting the absolutely positioned span in the other one, it's the same with two adjacent spans. Odd.

Comment: I think I got it. If the position is absolute, the inline element behaves like it has display: block. It is possible to set the width, height, margin, etc. Same thing if you set float to left. This changes the appearance of the element.

Answer (score 3):

The issue can be isolated as depending on `position: absolute`. Just adding it to the rules for a `span` that has `line-height: 1` changes its appearance. This depends on different height calculation algorithms for different kinds of elements (part of the tricky side of CSS).

Since your problem is that the non-positioned `span` is too tall, it might help to turn it to a block element (or inline block) in rendering: add

```
display: block
```

or

```
display: inline-block
```

for the `span`.

Comment: Really? You must be answering without reading (or you just copied the answer from) my comment. Either way, I figured it out 15 minutes before you did.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
<span style="background-color: #000; color: white; font-size: 300px;  padding: 0;float:left;">AAA</span>
<span style="background-color: #000; color: white; font-size: 300px;  padding: 0; position: absolute;float:left;">AAA</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CSPFL/1/